# Is there any built-in .NET Framework alternative for my extension method?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable

I got this nice method which I use in many cases.

```
internal static IEnumerable<TResult> RoundTrip<TSource, TResult>
 (this IEnumerable<TSource> e, Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> currentNextAction)
{
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumer = e.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumer.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        bool flag = true;
        TSource first = enumer.Current;

        do
        {
            TSource current = enumer.Current;
            TSource next = (flag = enumer.MoveNext()) ? enumer.Current : first;
            yield return currentNextAction(current, next);
        } while (flag);
    }
}
```

I have looked [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) for some built-in alternatives, but could not find them. Is there any?

And, is there anything I could improve in this code?

**EDIT**: New code for non-enumeratorable method.

```
internal static IEnumerable<TResult> RoundTrip<TSource, TResult>
 (this IEnumerable<TSource> e, Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> currentNextAction)
{
    bool flag = false;
    TSource first = default(TSource);
    TSource previous = default(TSource);

    foreach (TSource item in e)
    {
        if (!flag)
        {
            flag = true;
            first = previous = item;
            continue;
        }

        yield return currentNextAction(item, previous);
        previous = item;
    }

    if (flag)
        yield return currentNextAction(previous, first);
    else
        yield break;
}
```

(I like the first one by the way)

Comment: You might want to explain what it does. `RoundTrip()` isn't the most descriptive name...

Comment: Do you have a specific problem? Otherwise you may want to ask this on [`codereview.stackexchange.com`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Was is the intended behavior the code as it stands will iterate the ienumeraqble and progress one further returning the first element as both the first and last element and then stop. However from the name it sounds a bit like a "ring buffer" where you wish to start the enumeration over again after reaching the end...

Comment: Codereview does seem to make sense in terms of code improvement. One thing I will say is that very rarely do you need to use an enumerator directly and I don't think here is any different. You can save the current and next in a variable scoped outside of a foreach loop and then not have to worry about doing the movenext, checking the return value and all that manually.

Comment: @RuneFS: It looks to me like it loops through the enumerable running a given function against the current value and the one following it and for the last one (that doesn't have a following one) it uses the first.

Comment: @chris agreed it iterates the sequence and adds the first as the last element (as well as being the first) which was also what I tried to write in my comment and yes it does "something" to the elements in turn but that's not the part that I find confusing and thusI didn't mention it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built in for that, but you can really simplify it:

```
var lst = e.ToList();

lst.Add(lst[0]);
var result = lst.Take(lst.Count - 1).Select((x, i) => action(x, lst[i + 1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have Enumerable.Zip

```
var result = e.Zip(e.Skip(1).Concat(e.Take(1)), action)
```

it will of course enumerate the sequence twice (+1 element) unless you make a list first

Edit: Missed the roundtrip